# angularjs forEach and splice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array-splice

I have an array like this:

```
$scope.emails = [
  {"key":"Work","value":"user@domine.com"},
  {"key":"","value":""},
   {"key":"Work","value":"user2@domine.com"}
  {"key":"","value":""}];
```

So,  I want to remove empty emails but angular `forEach` method removing only one object that is last object why???.

**js code**

```
angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(email, index){
     if(email.value ===""){
       $scope.emails.splice(index, 1);

     } 

    });
```

where I am doing wrong

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/waxenusa/3/)

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question instead of just linking to JSBin.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The problem is that you remove elements from the array during the loop so later items are at different indices. You need to loop backwards instead:

```
for (var i = $scope.emails.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!$scope.emails[i].value) {
        $scope.emails.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Here's an [updated example](http://jsbin.com/waxenusa/5).

Comment: The second argument to `splice` indicates how many elements have to be removed, so if you can determine it before, you can do it also in one single `splice`. For example, you can remove the last two emails of your array with `$scope.emails.splice(1,2)` (or `$scope.emails.splice(1)`, which will remove everything after the first element).

Comment: @James Allardice Thanks for your replay. It's working fine. But my question is can't we do this using forEach

Comment: @chandu - No, `forEach` iterates over the array in the wrong direction so you'll have to use a normal loop.

Comment: @link - That's only going to work when the elements in question are adjacent to each other in the array. It's fine in this case but it isn't very robust.

Comment: @JamesAllardice of course, that's why I added "if you can determine it before" :) OP's question is not so clear, so I thought to add it as a remark in case his situation allows it.

Answer (score 3):

Like others have pointed out, the culprit of the code is the array got removed.  To get around with angular.forEach, you can try the additive/assignment approach:

```js
var filteredEmails = [];
angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(email, index){
    if(email.value !==""){
        filteredEmails.push(email);
    }
});

$scope.emails = filteredEmails;
```

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` returns `-1` when it doesn't find an item.

A way to remove an item, and to avoid removing the last one when not found, is:

```
var index = $scope.items.indexOf($scope.oldItem);

if (index != -1) {
  $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
describe('Foreach Splice', function () {
  it('splicing', function () {

    var elements = [
      {name: "Kelly", age: 16},
      {name: "", age: 17},
      {name: "Becky", age: 18},
      {name: "", age: 18},
      {name: "Sarah", age: 19},
      {name: "", age: 20},
      {name: "", age: 22},
      {name: "Mareck", age: 21},
      {name: "", age: 21},
      {name: "Mareck", age: 21}
    ];

    removeEmptyEntry(elements);
    console.log(elements);
  });


  function removeEmptyEntry(elements) {
    elements.forEach(function (element, index) {
      if (!element.name) {
        elements.splice(index, 1);
        removeEmptyEntry(elements);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Jut I want to remove empty values not 2nd index element

Comment: Ah what you mean is that you want to remove empty elements ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with AngularJs, but with Angular 4 a similar way of this works pretty well.

```
angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(email){
 if(email.value ===""){
   $scope.emails.splice($scope.emails.indexOf(email), 1);
 } 

});
```

Angular 4 version:

```
this.emailArray.forEach(email => {
  if (email.value == "") {
    this.emailArray.splice(this.emailArray.indexOf(email),1);
  }
});
```