# check array inside an array length is empty then remove the parent array from the main array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Hi How to check array inside an array length is empty then remove the parent array from the main array ,

think about i have an array

```
[
    {
        "id": 71,
        "campaignAssets": [
            {
                "id": 128
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 99,
        "campaignAssets": []
    }
]
```

from above array id:71 have campaignAssets array which is length is 1 but on the other one "id": 99 dont have the campaignAssets so i have to remove the parent array which means

```
    {
        "id": 99,
        "campaignAssets": []
    }
```

so **final array** should be

```
[
    {
        "id": 71,
        "campaignAssets": [
            {
                "id": 128
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

This proposal features two solutions,

1. generate a new array and assign it to the original array
2. delete unwanted items without generating a temporary.

**1. With a new array**

You could filter it with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var data = [{ "id": 71, "campaignAssets": [{ "id": 128 }] }, { "id": 99, "campaignAssets": [] }];

data = data.filter(function (a) { return a.campaignAssets.length; });

console.log(data);
```

In ES6 it's even shorter

```js
var data = [{ "id": 71, "campaignAssets": [{ "id": 128 }] }, { "id": 99, "campaignAssets": [] }];

data = data.filter(a => a.campaignAssets.length);

console.log(data);
```

**2. Without a new array**

For a in situ solution, keeping the array and delete only the elements with zero length, I suggest to use backward iteration and check the length and use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) accordingly.

```js
var data = [{ "id": 71, "campaignAssets": [{ "id": 128 }] }, { "id": 99, "campaignAssets": [] }],
    i = data.length;

while (i--) {
    if (!data[i].campaignAssets.length) {
        data.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I'd suggest keeping enforcing the callback on `.filter` of returning a boolean by `return (a.campaignAssets.length > 0)`

Comment: the callback itself uses a truthy/falsey value. *and constructs a new array of all the values for which callback returns a value that coerces to true.* [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data =[
    {
        "id": 71,
        "campaignAssets": [
            {
                "id": 128
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 99,
        "campaignAssets": []
    }
]
var i = data.length;
while (i--) {
    if(data[i].hasOwnProperty('campaignAssets') && data[i]['campaignAssets'].length==0)
       data.splice(i, 1)
}

// This one is wrong implementation as pointed out, it will not delete element from reducing array..
// data.forEach(function(parent,index){
//  if(parent.hasOwnProperty('campaignAssets') && parent['campaignAssets'].length==0)
//       data.splice(index, 1)
// });

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Your solution will skip some elements because of not decreasing loop index after splice, refer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24202962/5039495

Comment: thanks @Icycool , good catch. I updated my answer please check